# Printing two values using Runge Kutta Method

Tags: python, runge-kutta

I am trying to print b and c from this code, but I am not having any luck. If I am correct, this code should output several points with a step size of 0.05, but I am not seeing it. Does anyone know how to print two values from this code?

```
import math

def rK3(a, b, c, fa, fb, fc, hs):
    a1 = fa(a, b, c)*hs
    b1 = fb(a, b, c)*hs
    c1 = fc(a, b, c)*hs
    ak = a + a1*0.5
    bk = b + b1*0.5
    ck = c + c1*0.5
    a2 = fa(ak, bk, ck)*hs
    b2 = fb(ak, bk, ck)*hs
    c2 = fc(ak, bk, ck)*hs
    ak = a + a2*0.5
    bk = b + b2*0.5
    ck = c + c2*0.5
    a3 = fa(ak, bk, ck)*hs
    b3 = fb(ak, bk, ck)*hs
    c3 = fc(ak, bk, ck)*hs
    ak = a + a3
    bk = b + b3
    ck = c + c3
    a4 = fa(ak, bk, ck)*hs
    b4 = fb(ak, bk, ck)*hs
    c4 = fc(ak, bk, ck)*hs
    a = a + (a1 + 2*(a2 + a3) + a4)/6
    b = b + (b1 + 2*(b2 + b3) + b4)/6
    c = c + (c1 + 2*(c2 + c3) + c4)/6
    return a, b, c

def fa2(a, b, c):
    return 0.9*(1 - b*b)*a - b + math.sin(c)

def fb2(a, b, c):
    return a

def fc2(a, b, c):
    return 0.5

def VDP2():
    a, b, c, hs = 1, 1, 0, 0.05
    while (c<6):
        a, b, c = rK3(a, b, c, fa2, fb2, fc2, hs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not have any print statement, so it will not print.
Try inserting something like:

```
print 'b = {0}, c = {1}'.format(b,c)
```

Where you want the print to happen. For Python 3 just add parentheses (print is a function now)

```
print('b = {0}, c = {1}'.format(b,c))
```

Comment: Might want to update to show how to do it in Python 3 ;)

Comment: I tried to include your code at the end of my code, but it says b is not defined. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: @Cosmoman put it inside the `VDP2()` function and this solution should work.

Comment: @cosmoman You are missing a main portion in your script, if you want to do that. Also, you need to include the print statement within the integrator function. In any case, if you want to debug your code there are better ways.

Comment: Which portion am I missing? Also, what is a better way?

Comment: You can find a lot more info on Python [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/). To debug you can use `pdb`. SO is not the right platform to teach how to program.